# ZF2 Throw Error and Redirect within Module.php

Tags: zend-framework2

If have a Check within my `Module.php` and need to throw Error and Redirect to the error page.

Can someone please advice me how i can handle this?

```
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function ($e) use($serviceManager, $capture)
        {
   if($foo == null) {
   throw new \Exception("

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, although it requires you having your error templates mapped in your module.config:

```
$response = $e->getResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(500);
$response->sendHeaders();

//and in module.config
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
```