# How can I use custom exception pages with ZF2?

Tags: error-handling, zend-framework2, redirect

I need to redirect a user to an error page (`view/error/403.phtml`) from within the `Module.php` of a module called `Admin` when a user is not allowed to access the specific resource. I have been searching for a solution to this, but so far had no success. The best I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676639/zf2-throw-error-and-redirect-within-module-php), the accepted answer to which doesn't work for me  (and I currently cannot add comments to the linked question because I don't have the required reputation level) - the page is displayed as if there is no redirect at all and the user is allowed to access it. I have tried to replace the redirecting code with a simple `die;` to test if the `isAllowed()` is working properly, and it correctly shows a blank page, so the problem lies in the redirection itself.

Relevant code in `Module.php` is:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $this->initAcl($e);
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach('route', array($this, 'checkAcl'));
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
}

public function checkAcl(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // ...

    if (!$this->acl->isAllowed($userRole, $controller, $privilege))
    {
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $response->setHeaders($response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $e->getRequest()->getBaseurl() . '/error/403'));
        $response->setStatusCode(403);
        $response->sendHeaders();
    }

    // ...
}
```

`module.config.php`

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_exceptions' => true,
    'exception_template' => 'error/403',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/admin_layout.phtml',
        'error/403'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/403.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'Admin' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
    'strategies' => array(
        'ViewJsonStrategy',
    ),
),
```

If I add the line

```
throw new \Exception($translator->translate('Access denied'));
```

after the code for redirection, I do get redirected to URL `http://[servername]/error/403`, but the contents of the page is, instead of my custom `403.phtml`, a styled (with layout) 404 error page, stating that "The requested URL could not be matched by routing."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better way to achieve what you want is to trigger a `dispatch.error` event in your `checkAcl` function rather than trying to do a redirect. You can then handle this event and display the 403 page.

To trigger the event:

```
if (!$this->acl->isAllowed($userRole, $controller, $privilege))
{
    $app = $e->getTarget();
    $route = $e->getRouteMatch();

    $e->setError('ACL_ACCESS_DENIED') // Pick your own value, would be better to use a const
      ->setParam('route', $route->getMatchedRouteName());
    $app->getEventManager()->trigger('dispatch.error', $e);
}
```

Then in your onBootstrap add a listener for the `dispatch.error` event:

```
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
...

$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, <any callable>, -999);
```

In your callback for `dispatch.error` event you just attached to:

```
$error = $event->getError();

if (empty($error) || $error != "ACL_ACCESS_DENIED") {
    return;
}

$result = $event->getResult();

if ($result instanceof StdResponse) {
    return;
}

$baseModel = new ViewModel();
$baseModel->setTemplate('layout/layout');

$model = new ViewModel();
$model->setTemplate('error/403');

$baseModel->addChild($model);
$baseModel->setTerminal(true);

$event->setViewModel($baseModel);

$response = $event->getResponse();
$response->setStatusCode(403);

$event->setResponse($response);
$event->setResult($baseModel);

return false;
```

Comment: What is the full path of `StdResponse`? Is it an alias for `Zend\Http\Response`?

Comment: Also (when I replace `$event->setResult($base_model)` with a `$event->setResult($baseModel)`), in the output I only get the HTML from `layout/layout`, but not the **HTML** from `error/403`, even if the **variables** from `error/403` do seem to be correctly set (confirmed by them being used by `layout/layout`, for example for page title and one `<h1>` element), even with the line `<?php echo $this->layout()->content?>` in `layout/layout` unchanged.

Comment: I figured out how to render my child view. I did it by supplying a parameter name to `addChild` like `$baseModel->addChild($model, 'child');` and then `echo`ing `$this->child` if it is set in parent layout. Also I commented out the entire part with `StdResponse`. I will accept your answer, though, even if it needed some changes to work.

Comment: Hi, me too!, need to know what is StdResponse and which is its full path or if it's an alias... thanks!

Comment: @razor7 It is an alias for Zend\Stdlib\Response

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it works for me but display children don't ... `$this->layout()->getChildren()` in layout return `null`...